# Withdraw from a BTC wallet Ucoincash 24hours is still pending?

Tags: blockchain.info

I wanted to withdraw 0.62 Bitcoin back to my wallet and I did try to verify the receive wallet address as I submitted the request and it is still pending 24 hours later? On the blockchain, I see no transaction or received BTC? This request was sent Saturday Evening November 18th, 2017 at approximately 11 pm and it is 11 pm Sunday, November 19, 2017

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate. If it turns out that the transaction hasn't been broadcast to the network by the wallet service, then you would need to raise that with the service (in that case, the question would be off-topic for the site).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a copy of transaction (tx) ID or the address of the wallet that you sent it to? If so, go to https://blockchain.info/ and copy/paste one of those pieces of information into the search box in the top right-hand corner of the blockchain.info webpage and hit 'ENTER'. If the transaction went through okay it will show up on the blockchain.

Over the past few weeks there has been in increase in bitcoin transactions and the transfer times have slowed down. I also had a transfer that took over 24 hours. It isn't common, but does occur during peak times.

The bottom line is that as long as you got the right wallet address for the transfer the bitcoin will be on the blockchain (i.e. you won't have lost it).